# Some problems about serialization when i use spark read from hbase

Tags: apache-spark, hbase

I want to implement a `class` have a function that read from hbase by spark, like this:

```
public abstract class QueryNode implements Serializable{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -2961214832101500548L;
  private int id;
  private int parent;
  protected static Configuration hbaseConf;
  protected static Scan scan;
  protected static JavaSparkContext sc;
  public abstract RDDResult query();
  public int getParent() {
      return parent;
  }

  public void setParent(int parent) {
      this.parent = parent;
  }

  public int getId() {
      return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
      this.id = id;
  }
  public void setScanToConf() {
     try {
          ClientProtos.Scan proto = ProtobufUtil.toScan(scan);
          String scanToString = Base64.encodeBytes(proto.toByteArray());
          hbaseConf.set(TableInputFormat.SCAN, scanToString);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }}
```

This is a parent class, i hava some subclasses implement the menthod `query()` to read from hbase , but if I set `Configuration`, `Scan` and `JavaSparkContext` is not static, I will get some errors **: these classes are not serialized**.

Why these classes must be static? Have I some other ways to slove this problem? thks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to set `transient` for these fields to avoid serialization exception like

> Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException:
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext

so you say to java you just dont want to serialize these fields:

```
  protected transient Configuration hbaseConf;
  protected transient Scan scan;
  protected transient JavaSparkContext sc;
```

Are you initializing `JavaSparkContext`, `Configuration` and `Scan` in main or in any static method? With static, your fields are shared through all instancies. But it depends on your use cases if `static` should be used.

But with `transient` way it is better than `static` because **serialization of `JavaSparkCOntext` does not make sense** cause this is created on driver.

---

***-- edit after discussion in comment***:

[java doc for newAPIHadoopRDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaSparkContext.html#newAPIHadoopRDD(org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class))

```
public <K,V,F extends org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat<K,V>> JavaPairRDD<K,V> newAPIHadoopRDD(org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration conf,
                                                                                            Class<F> fClass,
                                                                                            Class<K> kClass,
                                                                                            Class<V> vClass)
```

> `conf` - Configuration for setting up the dataset. Note: This **will
>   be put into a Broadcast**. Therefore if you plan to reuse this `conf
>   to create multiple RDDs`, you need to **make sure you won't modify the
>   conf**. A safe approach is **always creating a new conf for a new
>   RDD**.

Broadcast:

> Broadcast variables allow the programmer to keep a **read-only variable** cached **on each machine** rather than shipping a copy of it with tasks.

So basically I think for that case `static` is ok (you create hbaceConf only once), but if you want to avoid `static`, you can follow suggestion in javadoc to always craete a new conf for a new RDD.

Comment: i test the transient to hbaseconf , but in cluster mode , it will happen to the error that class not found for hbase configuration, if i use static , don't hava this problem. do you  know the  general process that spark  connect hbase?  i  understand if i don't use static , every node should create the hbaseconf in local JVM, why spark need to serialize hbaseconf?

Comment: 1, Are you using [newAPIHadoopRDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaSparkContext.html#newAPIHadoopRDD(org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class)) in `public abstract RDDResult query();` implementation in the child? 2, you said "class not found for hbase configuration" -   which class was not found?

Comment: 1. yes, i use newAPIHadoopRDD in query() implementation in the child.

Comment: 2. the class is inline 'org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration'

Comment: 2.  the class  is   'org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration'

Comment: @yaowin check my answer I added some points. hbaseconf  is a broadcast variable for `newApiHadoopRDD`